# How do I avoid batch video transcoding error when encountering whitespaces in filename using ffmpeg

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I am running a bash script to batch transcode videos on a LAMP server using find and ffmpeg

```
dir="/srv/videos"
for OUTPUT in "$(find $dir -iname *.AVI -o -iname *.MOV)"
do
    ffmpeg -i "$OUTPUT" "${OUTPUT%%.*}.mp4"  -hide_banner
done
```

ffmpeg returns an error if file has whitespaces

```
 /srv/videos/file with white spaces.MOV: No such file or directory
```

For files without white spaces it works fine.
If I print the filenames inside quotes it looks as though it should be working

```
for OUTPUT in "$(find $dir -iname *.MOV)"; do echo "$OUTPUT";done
```

returns

```
/srv/videos/file with white spaces.MOV
```

What do I need to alter to avoid the error please?

**EDIT**
added "" to ${OUTPUT%%.*}.mp4, I get the same error and corrected extension capitalisation (mov to MOV)

Comment: You need quotes around `${OUTPUT%%.*}.mp4`.  The fact that the error message is coming back with the whole filename is because you quoted the input option - try the call manually with the same filename properly quoted. Maybe `ffmpeg` has a bug?

Comment: Separate concern - your `find` is looking for `*.MOV`, but your error message is saying `/srv/videos/file with white spaces.mov` - I assume you're on a windoze system (like me). Does it work manually if you change the case, but still fail if you don't? (I'd be surprised, but I'd certainly check it.)

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code, and its report contains enough information to lead you to a good solution.

Comment: `${OUTPUT%%.*}` may remove too much of the `OUTPUT` string.  `${OUTPUT%.*}` will remove only `.avi' or `.mov` (or `.Mov`, ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to get rid the for loop and just use the find command , eg smth like below :

```
find $dir -iname *.AVI -o -iname *.MOV | while read line; do ffmpeg -i "$line" ${line%%.*}.mp4  -hide_banner; done
```